# My script works only on page reloading when variant is selected

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I've made a jquery script that triggers a modal to show when a product is sold out
The script works fine, but only when the page is reloaded after the selection of the sold out product has been made (obviously also on first load of a product that is soldout).

So it seems that changing variants affects the script.
Is there a way to maybe reload the product page if a new variant that is sold out is selected? I've tried this method but won't work:
https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Design/Need-a-page-refresh-everytime-a-variant-changes-to-get-the/td-p/581219

The script i'm using:

```js
var modalproduct = new tingle.modal({
    footer: true,
    stickyFooter: false,
    closeMethods: ['overlay', 'button', 'escape'],
    closeLabel: "close",
    cssClass: ['custom-class-1', 'custom-class-2'],
    onOpen: function() {
        console.log('modal open');
    },
    onClose: function() {
        console.log('modal closed');
    },
    beforeClose: function() {
        // here's goes some logic
        // e.g. save content before closing the modal
        return true; // close the modal
        return false; // nothing happens
    }
});

// set content
modalproduct.setContent('dummy text');

    var btn2 = document.querySelector('.js-product');

    btn2.addEventListener('click', function(){
        modalproduct.open();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://tingle.robinparisi.com/tingle/tingle.js"></script>
<link href="https://tingle.robinparisi.com/tingle/tingle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a class="js-product" style="cursor: pointer;">{{- 'product.form.sold_out' | t -}}</a>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: What theme do you use? Can you give us a URL to check how it's already working?

Comment: https://www.momodesign.com/collections/caschi-moto-1/products/zero-heritage-nero-antracite-new?variant=31260853239919